# How can i get the probability throw many time to win 1 time?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a player who makes 15 throws, loses on the first 14 throws and wins only on the 15th throw?

Comment: Do we assume these "throws" are independent and we have an equal chance of win and loss?

Comment: yes we have the same chance and independent as well

Comment: What is the probability that the player who makes 1 throw, wins on the 1st throw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for each throw, win/loss are equally likely,

$$ P(W) = P(L) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Also, given that the throws are independent, we multiply the individual probabilities of the desired outcome for each throw to get the required probability.

So, we multiply 1/2 fifteen times (fourteen for the losses and one for the win). So, the required probability would be

$$P = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{15}$$